# Pipeline operator in scala

Tags: scala

Please, review my implementation of the F# pipeline operator in Scala

```
class PipelineContainer[F](value: F) {
  def |>[G] (f: F => G) = f(value)
}

implicit def pipelineEnrichment[T](xs: T) = new PipelineContainer(xs)

  test("Find the last but one element in the list") {
    // example: penultimate(List(1,2,3,3,4,5))
    // result: 4

    def reverse[T](list: List[T]) = list.reverse

    def head[T](list: List[T]) = list.head

    def tail[T](list: List[T]) = list.tail

    def lastButOne[T](list: List[T]) = list |> reverse |> tail |> head
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't much that can be reviewed. If you use Scala 2.10 then you should use an [implicit class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/implicit-classes.html) instead of an implicit conversion. Even better: use an implicit [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html):

```
implicit class PipelineContainer[F](val value: F) extends AnyVal {
  def |>[G] (f: F => G) = f(value)
}
```

Furthermore, in Scala, type parameter are enumerated starting with an `A`, but this is more a style issue.